# Search for and zoom in to a scatter plot point (Highcharts, react.js)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, reactjs

I'm using the highcharts library in react.js and it's working great. However, I'm plotting ~15,000 scattered points and it's a bit tricky finding the one I want among all that. I'd like to be able to search for a specific point, since each point has its own unique name property along with its x and y coordinates (not id, but I could put the name as id if that made the solution easier). When the point is found, the graph should zoom in a bit, since at default zoom level there's quite a few overlaps of points so just making it blink/bigger/something wouldn't help much. I've looked through the Highcharts API docs but I can't find anything that will do a manual zoom into specified coordinates.

I found the `mapZoom` function, but that's only for maps, and... well, this isn't a map. It's a scatter plot.

Also, since this is react, it's a bit tricky to see how I can access the chart object to do stuff with it, since the only time it exists is when it's being returned to be rendered:

```js
var CosinePlot = React.createClass({
 componentDidMount: function() {
  let chart = this.refs.chart.getChart();
 },

 render: function() {
  return <ReactHighcharts config={plotConfig} isPureConfig={true}/>;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know exact point you want to zoom in, simply get it's `x` and `y`. Then zoom into that point using `chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)` and `chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)`.

And regarding accessing the chart object, I guess you are using this [this wrapper](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts). There is an explanation how to retrieve that chart object [here](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts#accessing-highcharts-api-after-render).

Comment: How do I access that chart variable from other functions? I'll need to use the ```setExtremes``` calls in response to button clicks etc., which won't necessarily happen in ```componentDidMount```.

Comment: For reference, I ended up using ```chart.xAxis[0].zoom(min,max)``` and ```chart.showResetZoom()``` to accomplish my zooming, because I couldn't get the reset button to show up until I found an answer that pointed me to these calls. Also needed ```chart.redraw()```.

Comment: You can store chart object in a variable when creating a chart. Or, when using jQuery, you can get chart using `var chart = $("#container").highcharts()`. Or, if you have only one chart on the website, use `var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];`. Of course, if you want to get `Reset Zoom` button, then call `chart.showResetZoom()`. Note, that `showResetZoom()` function is not part of the official API.